# how to handle SQL failer from asterisk dial plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, lua, asterisk, unixodbc

Im using

- Asterisk certified/16.8-cert2
- MSSQL Express 2014
- unixODBC 2.3.1
- freetds v1.1.20
- Lua 5.1.4
- CentOS7

I doing **update statement** in SQL with  func_odbc.so. The update statement is working fine with no issue. but I wanna away to be able to catch an error if it happens, like a disconnect or network interruption.

Here is my update statement

```
  UPDATE Customers SET AccountBalance = AccountBalance - ${VAL1} WHERE cif = ${ARG1}
```

My dialPlan function call ( in extention.lua)

`local  statues = channel.ODBC_ErrorTest(1499):set(10)`

One of the thing that I  though I can make it work, is by adding TRY and CATCH blook in the SQL statement itself like below, so if there is an error it will return the error number

```
BEGIN TRY 
  UPDATE Customers SET AccountBalance = AccountBalance - a WHERE cif = 17399 
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
 SELECT   ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber 
END CATCH
```

But when I try to execute this it does not  return me an error number when there is a failer, just return an empty string.

So my question is simple, how to handle SQL failer from the dial plan?

Comment: [From docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15): The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:

Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.

Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution

Comment: I'm sorry I read the documentation but I believe I miss understand, so what should I look for in SQL to know if a commit to the database is actually successfully happening @Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For update it should return -1 in case of writesql error.

However you should understand, asterisk is PBX, not something suitable for complex sql check.

Possible workarounds

1) create other table with command, create external script which check it for new "actions" and send back results/error. Check in asterisk after 0.5sec, 1sec etc.

2) create simple rest API and use func_CURL.

Comment: **it does not return -1**  ( or maybe I can't get it in dialplan). but what I see in my  case of err, . It returns **nil**  wither everything went successful or failed. @arheops

Comment: I don't know why you have problem test yourself. http://prntscr.com/ss3js0

Comment: I was looking in the wrong location. I was looking at the return values from `local  statues = channel.ODBC_ErrorTest(1499):set(10)`, but in reality I should check the channel variable ` local  statues = channel.ODBCSTATUS:get()` . Tq  very much

Comment: I'm kinda unclear about "creating  other table with command " do you mean create anther table is the database which  I update it after every transaction then after few 0.x seconds check it to see if everything is successful @arheops

Comment: table operations(id serial, sql text, compleated boolean, result text). insert in it. AFter that external script do sql with error checks. Again, asterisk is PBX, you want too much.